# Как считать данные из excel исключительно в текстовом формате с помощью XLRD

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlrd

```
rb = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info = True)
cl = ['DI', 'DO', 'AI', 'AO', 'M', 'Event', 'VALVE', 'MODULE']
for i in cl:
    if i in rb.sheet_names():
        sheet = rb.sheet_by_name(i)
        log("Проверка " + i)
        for rownum in range(1, sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row_values(rownum)
            eval(i)(row, rownum)
```

Все ячейки в Excel имеют текстовый формат.

Если в первой ячейке хранится '9',
то row[0] даст 9.0 , а мне нужно '9'

Мне принципиально важно различать значения ячеек 9 и 9.0

Можно ли используя XLRD, как то указать, чтоб забирала всё только в текстовом формате из EXCEL?

Comment: Уточните формат данных в каждой строке. cell().value как и row_values() выводит данные как есть, за исключением форматов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось в excel`e 2010 есть одна странность:

Если ранее формат ячейки был числовой и ячейка хранила число, то после смены формата через ПКМ, формат ячеек ...   на самом деле он не меняется, хоть и показывается что текстовый. Чтоб он действительно стал текстовый, нужно удалить значение и потом заново его ввести, вот тогда ячейка действительно сменит формат и питон это увидит через row_value().

Answer (score 2):

А вы уверены, что в Excel документе ячейки текстовые? Метод `row_values()` выдает данные в исходном виде.

Если выдает 9.0, значит в исходном документе стоит формат "Числовой".

Если необходимо получить текст независимо от формата ячейки исходного документа, можете воспользоваться например методом `sheet.cell_type(rowx, colx)` для определения типа данных в ячейке:

- 1 - "текстовый" выводим как есть.
- 2 - "числовой" округляем и приводим к строке.
- 3 - "Дата" Преобразуем дату в текст.

Подробности [здесь](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: Создал тестовый документ, в столбец занес числа. Показывает тип 2, хотя формат - текст.

Comment: Значит не текст, я только что попробовал у себя, если формат "текстовый" выводится строка '9', посмотрите внимательнее формат ячейки. Ещё бывает "общий", он по моему автоматически определяет формат.

Comment: С присвоением типов проблемы у libreoffice.  '9', то row[0] даст 9.0 - тут явно формат не текст, иначе вывело бы '9'

Comment: числовой тип выводит как число без сохранения формата, число два знака после запятой 5,00 будет выведено как 5,0. Тип 2.

Comment: У меня Excel 2010. Формат всех ячеек, абсолютно всех, текстовый, ни общий ни числовой, именно текстовый, но метод row_values() всё равно достаёт 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернативный вариант определения.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb_read = open_workbook('test.xls', formatting_info=True)
ws = wb_read.sheets()[0]


def dump_cell(sheet, rowx, colx):
    c = sheet.cell(rowx, colx)
    xf = sheet.book.xf_list[c.xf_index]
    fmt_obj = sheet.book.format_map[xf.format_key]
    print(rowx, colx, repr(c.value), c.ctype, fmt_obj.type, fmt_obj.format_key, fmt_obj.format_str)


dump_cell(sheet=ws, rowx=1, colx=4)  # лист(объект), ячейка(строка, столбец)
```

Одной строкой, для текста выведет @

```
print((ws.book.format_map[(ws.book.xf_list[ws.cell(1, 3).xf_index]).format_key]).format_str)
```

Функция для того чтобы узнать формат ячейки, выводит все, но можете оставить только нужные. Для текста выводит @, для числового формата, 2 знака после запятой 0.00, и т.п.